# KeyError: Caught KeyError in DataLoader worker process 0

Tags: python, pytorch, hdf5

I am facing this error which is related to the dictionary of data loader for (MSVD dataset) while running training file for video_captioning on https://github.com/nasib-ullah/video-captioning-models-in-Pytorch

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
code of  **getitem** function :

```
 def __getitem__(self,idx): 
        
        anno = random.choice(self.annotation_dict[self.v_name_list[idx]])
        anno_index = []
        for word in anno.split(' '):
            try:
                anno_index.append(self.voc.word2index[word])
            except:
                pass 
        if self.opt_truncate_caption:
            if len(anno_index)> self.max_caption_length:
                anno_index = anno_index[:self.max_caption_length]
        anno_index = anno_index + [self.voc.cfg.EOS_token]
        appearance_tensor = torch.tensor(self.appearance_feature_dict[self.v_name_list[idx]]).float()
        
        if self.motion_feature_dict == None:
            motion_tensor = torch.zeros_like(appearance_tensor)
        else:
             motion_tensor = torch.tensor(self.motion_feature_dict[self.v_name_list[idx]]).float()
        if self.object_feature_dict == None:
            object_tensor = torch.zeros_like(appearance_tensor)
        else:
            object_tensor = torch.tensor(self.object_feature_dict[self.v_name_list[idx]]).float()
            
        return appearance_tensor,anno_index, self.v_name_list[idx],motion_tensor,object_tensor
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/home/adel/Downloads/video-captioning-models-in-Pytorch-main/untitled0.py", line 84, in <module>
    loss_train,ac_loss = model.train_epoch(train_loader,utils)

  File "/home/adel/Downloads/video-captioning-models-in-Pytorch-main/models/MARN/model.py", line 321, in train_epoch
    for data in dataloader:

  File "/home/adel/anaconda3/envs/nasib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 435, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()

  File "/home/adel/anaconda3/envs/nasib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1085, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)

  File "/home/adel/anaconda3/envs/nasib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1111, in _process_data
    data.reraise()

  File "/home/adel/anaconda3/envs/nasib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 428, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)

KeyError: Caught KeyError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adel/anaconda3/envs/nasib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 198, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/adel/anaconda3/envs/nasib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/adel/anaconda3/envs/nasib/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/adel/Downloads/video-captioning-models-in-Pytorch-main/data.py", line 88, in __getitem__
    appearance_tensor = torch.tensor(self.appearance_feature_dict[self.v_name_list[idx]]).float()
KeyError: 'vid1'
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

keys of dictionary

```
Keys: <KeysViewHDF5 ['vid1', 'vid10', 'vid100', 'vid1000', 'vid1001', 'vid1002', 'vid1003', 'vid1004', 'vid1005', 'vid1006',   ...

<HDF5 dataset "vid1": shape (28, 1536), type "<f4">
```

Comment: That is a mountain of code to go thru. Have you tried creating a MVCE (minimal, complete and verifiable example) that replicates the problem? Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).